# Kendo batch edit Grid fails when updating more than 40 + rows

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a `Kendo UI for MVC` batch edit grid that will not update to the server once I have about 40+ rows of data being updated. I can update each of the rows individually or several at a time but once I have more than about 40 rows, it error somewhere in the `jquery.1.7.2.js script`. I have verified that the data I am using is not the issue. I have a ticket with Kendo but they say there is no such limitation. There are 13 columns but I am only updating 6 of them, I have hard coded the data in most of the string columns to "test" to try and minimize the amount of data.

Is there anyone who has a batch edit grid and can update more than say 50 rows at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved. It was not the number of rows, rater the number of key pairs. The default is set to 1000 to stop Denial of Service attacks. Here is a link to an article from MS explaining the issue. [MS Article](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238386)

In short, here is the setting in the web config file, I bumpped the value to 10,000 and stopped getting the error.

```
<configuration>
<appSettings>
<add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="10000" />
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```